# Hashing of Key-Value pair on Hashpass.com

Tags: encryption, hash

Just found this website: hashpass.com and here is the JS implementation which they use to encrypt the key-value pair: http://hashapass.com/sha1.js

So, can there be a "simple" and obvious alternative to this?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need an alternative?

Comment: Best way to achieve the same functionality without using SHA

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how secure this is. For one thing, the output is a short Base64 string. Due to its length and restricted character set, it should be easier to brute-force than a regular password that avoids the common and dictionary values while combining alpha, numeric and other.

Comment: It looks to me like straight SHA-1 and HMAC-SHA1 with base64 encoding. I'm not much of a javascript programmer; can you explain where the "short" part comes in?

Comment: If you go to the top page of the site, it lets you enter a master password and a parameter. After I typed two long values, it spat out: QQl04Flu

Answer (score 0):

You want it to be simpler in **`<what?>`** way? You want it to be more obvious in **`<what?>`** way?

Do you care about the cryptographic strength?

If you don't care about that, you can simply take a sum modulo 2<<32 (or something) and encode the result as 8 hex digits.

**I sure wouldn't trust my logon to that kind of security** , but is

1. simple
2. obvious